# Techniques to analyze urbanization pattern using population and urban area data?

Tags: data-analysis

I have some cities' population data (number) and urban area (sq.m.) of 3 consecutive years (1991,2001&2011). I want to get the patterns of urbanization of those cities.

Could anyone suggest how to do that using depth & standards methods?

Comment: I have also the raster of urban area as geotiff image.

Comment: what is meant by depth and standards methods?

Comment: it could be done through calculating two variables' yearly change and comparing population change with area change. But I'm seeking any other method that is acceptable by academician and that can find out actual urbanization pattern.